# how to get data into string against guid and dropdownlist in SSRS?

Tags: ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm-2011, guid

I am working on SSRS reports from using dynamics CRM 2011 as a data source. I have a dropdown list that include the tile like Mr and Mrs. and a lookup that contains some sort of cities.

Now the problem is that when I am creating the report the brings data against each field but no in strings. For example, there is a complete guid of 32 characters instead name of the city and there 1 and 2 against Mr and Mrs title.

Please suggest me the best way to resolve this issue. Or help me to overcome the problem or convert the guid etc into against there strings.

Your kind help will encourage me.

Comment: Are you using T-SQL or FetchXML?

Answer (score 1):

When you use a fetchXML dataset there are matching "Value" fields that will contain the actual text value.
You should see a cityValue field in your fetchXML dataset.
This applies for both lookups and optionsets.